# Adding data to new column in table (insert into or update)

Tags: sql, sybase

What I try to achieve is to update all data, so the new data goes into Row_ID and all other columns.

I have a table created db.test
I added new column Row_ID(integer)

This ise the first Code for inserting data to table

```
 Insert into db.test
    (
      STRING0 ,
      CONTACT ,
      STRING2 ,
      TEMPLATE,
      NAME ,
      EXEC_ID, 
      SENDDATE,
      OPENDATE,
      CLICKDATE
    ) 
    SELECT 
      acc.STRING0 ,
      a.CONTACT ,
      acc.STRING2 ,
      a.TEMPLATE ,
      a.NAME ,
      a.EXEC_ID, 
      a.SENDDATE,
      A.OPENDATE,
      A.CLICKDATE 
    FROM db.account acc 
    Join db.activity a  
      ON acc.object_id = a.rep_contact
    left JOIN db.VAL v1 
      ON v1.row_id = a.CAMPAIGN_TYPE 
     AND (v1.OBJ_FIELD_ID in(850)) 
    left JOIN db.VAL v2 
      ON v2.row_id = a.CAMPAIGN_TYPE 
     AND (v2.OBJ_FIELD_ID in(851))
```

The values for ROW_ID comes from table db.VAL, but do I use update like this

```
Update db.test
( row_id, -- This column as integer has greated
 string0, 
 etc...)
 Select
 v1.row_Id,
 acc.STRING0,
 etc....
 Ending is the same
```

I tried this kind of update query, but it didn't work.
What should I change?
Because I would prefer to just update table, not drop, create new, and all new data.

NB! SQL Server ( Sybase)

Comment: you have to use `SET`

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do here... Do you want to replace rows? All of them, or just some?

Comment: I have on columns STRING0 ,
  CONTACT ,
  STRING2 ,
  TEMPLATE,
  NAME ,
  EXEC_ID, 
  SENDDATE,
  OPENDATE,
  CLICKDATE
Data inserted, but I found out that I need to add new column with data.
So I don't want to drop the table, but add data for that specific column Aka ROW_ID

Comment: please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As data is already inserted in the table, now you will have to update
the values in new column `row_id`. Following pseudo code will work
just make sure the from clause fetches the correct value of v1.row_Id:

```
UPDATE   db.test 
SET row_id = v1.row_Id
FROM db.test t1
JOIN db.account acc ON acc.STRING0 = t1.STRING0 
--all match columns will go here
AND  acc.STRING2 = t1.STRING2
JOIN db.activity a  ON acc.[object_id] = a.rep_contact 
AND  a.CONTACT = t1.CONTACT
AND  a.TEMPLATE = t1.TEMPLATE
AND  a.NAME = t1.NAME
AND a.EXEC_ID = t1.EXEC_ID
AND a.SENDDATE = t1.SENDDATE
AND A.OPENDATE = t1.OPENDATE
AND A.CLICKDATE = t1.CLICKDATE
LEFT JOIN db.VAL v1 ON v1.row_id = a.CAMPAIGN_TYPE 
AND (v1.OBJ_FIELD_ID in(850))   
LEFT JOIN db.VAL v2 ON v2.row_id = a.CAMPAIGN_TYPE 
AND (v2.OBJ_FIELD_ID in(851))
```

Comment: By "all match columns will go here" you mean 
I will add them like this 
(Column 1, Column 2, Column 3,) ?

Comment: No by that I meant to update `db.Test` table you will have to match each row in same table with rest of the data (from all other tables) ex: `acc.STRING2 = t1.STRING2`